# Nesting a flat array in on itself

Tags: php5

I have an extremely large function for turning my database output of menu links into a multidimensional array that nests each of the links in a menu fashion. I'm wondering if anyone sees a way this class function can be shortened or simplified in some way.

The mysqli query:

```
private function _interactions($product, $permissions, $mymenu){
    $myMenuArray = !empty($mymenu) ? explode(",", $mymenu) : NULL;
    $myDBMenuArray = array();
    $stmt = $this->mysqli->select("SELECT * FROM skss_".$product."_menu WHERE permissions >= ?", array($permissions), array("%i"));
    if(count($stmt)>0 && empty($myMenuArray)){
        array_walk($stmt, (function(&$item){$item = (array)$item;}));
        $myDBMenuArray = array_merge($stmt);
    }
    else if(count($stmt)>0){
        foreach($stmt as $obj){
            $found = array_search($obj->data_target, $myMenuArray);
            if($found !== FALSE){ $myDBMenuArray[] = (array)$obj; }
        }
    }
    return $this->_buildMenuAndActions($myDBMenuArray);
}
```

Which returns this array from the DB:

```
Array
 (
     [0] => Array
         (
             [data_target] => '#address-modal'
             [ancor_value] => 'Address Dialog'
             [inmenu] => 0
             [static] => 1
             [keyboard] => 1
             [name] => 'address-modal-link'
             [href] => 
             [menuID] => 
             [permissions] => 9
         )

     [1] => Array
         (
             [data_target] => '#error-modal'
             [ancor_value] => 'Error Modal'
             [inmenu] => 0
             [static] => 1
             [keyboard] => 1
             [name] => 'error-modal-link'
             [href] => 
             [menuID] => 
             [permissions] => 9
         )

     [2] => Array
         (
             [data_target] => '#message-modal'
             [ancor_value] => 'Message Modal'
             [inmenu] => 0
             [static] => 1
             [keyboard] => 0
             [name] => 'message-modal-link'
             [href] => 
             [menuID] => 
             [permissions] => 9
         )

     [3] => Array
         (
             [data_target] => '#mytarget'
             [ancor_value] => 'unknown'
             [inmenu] => 0
             [static] => 1
             [keyboard] => 1
             [name] => 'mytarget'
             [href] => 
             [menuID] => '#address-modal'
             [permissions] => 9
         )

     [4] => Array
         (
             [data_target] => '#mytarget2'
             [ancor_value] => 'mytarget'
             [inmenu] => 0
             [static] => 1
             [keyboard] => 1
             [name] => 'mytarget'
             [href] => 
             [menuID] => '#address-modal'
             [permissions] => 0
         )

     [5] => Array
         (
             [data_target] => '#mytarget3'
             [ancor_value] => 'mytarget3'
             [inmenu] => 0
             [static] => 1
             [keyboard] => 1
             [name] => 'mytarget3'
             [href] => 
             [menuID] => '#mytarget'
             [permissions] => 9
         )

     [6] => Array
         (
             [data_target] => '#user-modal'
             [ancor_value] => 'User Dialog'
             [inmenu] => 0
             [static] => 1
             [keyboard] => 1
             [name] => 'user-modal-link'
             [href] => 
             [menuID] => 
             [permissions] => 9
         )

     [7] => Array
         (
             [data_target] => '#userImage-modal'
             [ancor_value] => 'User Image Modal'
             [inmenu] => 0
             [static] => 1
             [keyboard] => 0
             [name] => 'userImage-modal-link'
             [href] => 
             [menuID] => 
             [permissions] => 9
         )

     [8] => Array
         (
             [data_target] => '#wait-modal'
             [ancor_value] => 'Wait/Loading Modal'
             [inmenu] => 0
             [static] => 1
             [keyboard] => 0
             [name] => 'wait-modal-link'
             [href] => 
             [menuID] => 
             [permissions] => 9
         )

 )
```

This is my rather very complicated class function for turning all my links into menu nested items.

```
private function _buildMenuAndActions($interactions, $myList = array()){
    $myMenu = array();
    foreach($interactions as $interaction){
        // First layers.
        // If $interaction['menuID'] would ever purposely be a zero (for 
        // instance as a numerical row ID), this would need to be a 
        // "=== NULL" comparison and NULL would need to be maintained 
        // on the DB.  
        if(empty($interaction['menuID'])){
            $searchFor = $interaction['data_target'];
            $filteredArray = 
            array_filter($interactions, function($element) use($searchFor){
              return isset($element['menuID']) && $element['menuID'] == $searchFor;
            });
            $myMenu[] = array("link" => $this->_create($interaction), "children" => !empty($filteredArray) ? $this->_buildMenuAndActions($filteredArray, $interactions) : array());
        }
        // Layers with nestable layers.
        else if(
                    !empty($myList) && (array_search($interaction['data_target'], array_column($myList, 'menuID')) !== FALSE)
                ){
            $searchFor = $interaction['data_target'];
            $filteredArray = 
            array_filter($myList, function($element) use($searchFor){
              return isset($element['menuID']) && $element['menuID'] == $searchFor;
            });
            $myMenu[] = array("link" => $this->_create($interaction), "children" => !empty($filteredArray) ? $this->_buildMenuAndActions($filteredArray, $myList) : array());
        }
        // Layers without nestable layers.
        else if(
                    !empty($myList) && !(array_search($interaction['data_target'], array_column($myList, 'menuID')) !== FALSE)
                ){
            $searchFor = $interaction['data_target'];
            $filteredArray = 
            array_filter($interactions, function($element) use($searchFor){
              return isset($element['menuID']) && $element['menuID'] == $searchFor;
            });
            $myMenu[] = array("link" => $this->_create($interaction), "children" => !empty($filteredArray) ? $this->_buildMenuAndActions($filteredArray) : array());
        }
    }
    return $myMenu;
}
```

Example output:

```
Array
 (
     [0] => Array
         (
             [link] => '#address-modal'
             [children] => Array
                 (
                     [0] => Array
                         (
                             [link] => '#mytarget'
                             [children] => Array
                                 (
                                     [0] => Array
                                         (
                                             [link] => '#mytarget3'
                                             [children] => Array
                                                 (
                                                 )

                                         )

                                 )

                         )

                     [1] => Array
                         (
                             [link] => '#mytarget2'
                             [children] => Array
                                 (
                                 )

                         )

                 )

         )

     [1] => Array
         (
             [link] => '#error-modal'
             [children] => Array
                 (
                 )

         )

     [2] => Array
         (
             [link] => '#message-modal'
             [children] => Array
                 (
                 )

         )

     [3] => Array
         (
             [link] => '#user-modal'
             [children] => Array
                 (
                 )

         )

     [4] => Array
         (
             [link] => '#userImage-modal'
             [children] => Array
                 (
                 )

         )

     [5] => Array
         (
             [link] => '#wait-modal'
             [children] => Array
                 (
                 )

         )

 )
```

So, ah. Any ideas for simplifying this?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I feel as if there would be some much easier (and faster!?) way of doing this with SQL?  Assuming you have a sensible DBMS and table structure.  Is writing a different query not an option here?

Comment: Added my mysqli query.

Comment: @SirPython. Thanks, I had some help. Community edit, "request" for sql info, etc. Very helpful community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can simplify your code, since it has three blocks almost identical. The only differences are:

- `$filteredArray` comes from either `$interactions` or `$myList`.
- `$myMenu[]['children']` is built using either `$interactions`, `$myList`, or an empty array.

So instead of working three times depending on three if/else branchs, you can factorize the working part and call it after having defined the needed values.
Not only it ends with a reduced code but also a more readable one, where the logic part is clearly separated.

Here is a suggested version using the above changes, where I also slightly changed the expression of the `!empty($myList)` condition, for readability and DRYness:

```
private function _buildMenuAndActions($interactions, $myList = []) {
  $myMenu = [];
  foreach ($interactions as $interaction) {
    if ($interaction['menuID'] === NULL) {
      // First layers.
      $this->_doBuildMAA($interaction, $myMenu, $interactions, $interactions);
    } else {
      if (!empty($myList)) {
        if (array_search($interaction['data_target'], array_column($myList, 'menuID'))) {
          // Layers with nestable layers.
          $this->_doBuildMAA($interaction, $myMenu, $myList, $myList);
        } else {
          // Layers without nestable layers.
          $this->_doBuildMAA($interaction, $myMenu, $interactions, []);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return $myMenu;
}
private function _doBuildMAA($interaction, &$myMenu, $filterFrom, $buildFrom) {
  $searchFor = $interaction['data_target'];
  $filteredArray = array_filter($filterFrom, function($element) use ($searchFor) {
    return isset($element['menuID']) && $element['menuID'] == $searchFor;
  });
  $myMenu[] = [
    "link" => $this->_create($interaction),
    "children" => !empty($filteredArray) ?
      $this->_buildMenuAndActions($filteredArray, $buildFrom) : []
  ];
}
```

Comment: It's not nesting out of the box brah, I'll review and figure out why. I like the suggested edits though. Very nice. I learned a lot from your answer.

Comment: Oh man, I've got to have my four spaces or I'm really bad at reading code.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but can you follow people on here? I'd like to see answers and comments by @cFreed.

Comment: $myList is always empty.

Comment: Having problems I think with the NULL nesting. // Never mind. I'm not done reviewing yet

Comment: @EricShoberg Huh... you're lucky I came back here now: I should be in bed, since for me it' 5 AM. Don't clearly understand your comments (note: English is not my mother language): what do you mean with "got to have my four spaces"? In the other hand, not understand your proposed edit too: what is this "added parenthesis"?

Comment: @EricShoberg Ok, I just understood about the edit. For anything else, feel free to ask, but note that for now I'm not here any longer. Back tomorrow.

Comment: You used two space tabs indents, I like to use four, it makes the code more readable for me. Your other question, there was a parenthesis missing.

Comment: Okay, I got this working. The only issue was the needed parenthesis and a problem I had in my own DB. The new functions work great. Thanks @cFreed.

Comment: @EricShoberg Well, now I understand all, including the parenthesis I'd missed. Sorry for that. Regarding the indentation, I know there are a lot of guys which prefer 4 spaces, while strangely it's the opposite for me: I can't think quietly as long as there are too much (at my eyes) spaces and blank lines in the code! It's a bit astonishing to see that we can be so different... Anyway, glad to help!